# Detect the app version in Google play via Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play

Google has updated its UI for Google Play Store. I was able to get the app version from a simple request/response for an app with the old UI.

My app is written with Flutter & Dart.
How to detect the app version in Google play? is there any way to fix it.

I got this from Google play via email: If you would like to fetch these details from an API, you may review our [Google Play Developer API setup documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) to enable our [Publishing API methods](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher#publishing). You may refer to edits.tracks method in order to fetch the release versions of all your active tracks.

How to call Google play api from fluttar app and get the published app version?

Best regards

Comment: you can use google_play_scraper package.[Google play scraper](https://pub.dev/packages/google_play_scraper)

Comment: @Sifat I don't want to use any package. How to call Google play api from fluttar app and get the published app version?